# How to enable Drag and Drop on Pivot Control UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I really like the Pivot Control and how you can swipe between pages on a touchscreen. It responds like a Tab control and works very well. My problem is I would like to drag and drop to reorder pivot items. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code I have for the pivot.

```
<Pivot x:Name="PivotMain" CanDrag="True" AllowDrop="True" FontFamily="Segoe UI" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="Black"  >
                <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="13" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <PivotItem x:Name="Main" Header="Home" CanDrag="True" FontSize="11" Margin="10,10,10,10" FontFamily="Segoe UI" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <WebView x:Name="Home" DefaultBackgroundColor="Transparent" NavigationCompleted="NavigationCompleted"  NewWindowRequested="NewWindowRequested" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </PivotItem>
            </Pivot>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Pivot` control inherit from `ItemsControl` but not `ListViewBase`. So it does not contain `CanDragItems` `CanReorderItems` property, you could not reorder them like `ListView`. `Pivot` has `ItemsSource` property, it means that your could bind with `ObservableCollection`. and reorder it with reordering data source.

```
<Pivot
    x:Name="PivotMain"
    Margin="0,0,0,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    AllowDrop="True"
    BorderBrush="Black"
    FontFamily="Segoe UI"
    >
    <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <PivotItem
                CanDrag="True"
                FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                FontSize="11"
                Header="{Binding}"
                >
                <Frame />
            </PivotItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="0,0,0,0"
                    FontSize="13"
                    Text="{Binding}"
                    />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

**Code behind**

```
 ObservableCollection<string> Items;
 public MainPage()
 {
     Items = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "first", "second", "third", "forth" };
     PivotMain.ItemsSource = Items;
     this.InitializeComponent();
 }
```

**Reorder**

```
var _timer = new Timer(async _ =>
{
    Random r = new Random();
    var randomIndex = r.Next(0, Items.Count - 1);
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
        Items.Insert(4, Items[randomIndex]);
        Items.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
    });
}
, null, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I think what I'll try to do is when the Drag is initiated I'll convert the headers into a listviewbase, allow the user to reorganize and then when they're finished the Pivot will change the order based on the index of the horizontal listview.